# Issue with an API : Can not deserialize instance ... out of START_OBJECT token \n

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have a rest Template that call an API.
This should returns a list of usernames, here is the call result :

```
{"userName":"user1"}
{"userName":"user2"}
{"userName":"user3"}
```

As you can see, this is not really a JSON Format, so when I'm Calling my restTemplate :

```
restTemplate.postForObject(MONITORING + QUERY, request, MyCustomClass[].class);
```

Where MyCustomClass is :

```
public class EndpointCallEvents {
    private String userName;
}
```

I have the Following error :

```
Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of [mypackage].MyCustomClass[] out of START_OBJECT token \n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@25d18d7; line: 1, column: 1]
```

But if I call without array on MyCustomClass, I get only one result :

```
restTemplate.postForObject(MONITORING + QUERY, request, MyCustomClass.class);
```

So I tried with a fake JSON : I got the String result, put "[" and "]", and replace \n characters with comma, except for the last object.
Then when Calling the restTemplate with MyCustomClass[].class, I retrieve array of MyCustomClass objects.

So I was wondering, how can I call my restTemplate and parse it into a "real JSON" or whatever, in order to have object array, and avoid to get the String first, then parse it etc etc

Thanks guys!

Comment: How did u know the response is not JSON. How did u print the response ?

Comment: By a post request on Postman, that is json objects but it seems that each object is independant, there is no JSON structure with brackets and comma

Comment: try setting "Accept" header as application/json in postman see what u get.